# java script alert on button press

Tags: javascript, java, button

I want this to happen when I press a button, not when i open/refresh the site. Can someone help me with that? :) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getRate(from, to) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rate%2Cname%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.finance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes%3Fs%3D"+from+to+"%253DX%26f%3Dl1n'%20and%20columns%3D'rate%2Cname'&format=json&callback=parseExchangeRate");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
  function parseExchangeRate(data) {
    var name = data.query.results.row.name;
    var rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);
    alert("Exchange rate " + name + " is " + rate);
  }
  getRate("USD", "NOK");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onclick attribute of a button:

`<button onclick="getRate('USD', 'NOK')">clickme</button>`

and remove the call to `getRate()` from the end of your script so it is not called on page load.